# Using multiprocessing.pool.Pool to initialize parallel processing freezes indefinitely

Tags: python, parallel-processing, anaconda, spyder

I am currently trying to run parallelized code from a spyder console in anaconda. I believe the issue may be with my computer not allowing anaconda to control CPU cores, but I am not sure how to correct this issue.

Another interesting point is that when I run an async example, but when I try to produce the results I receive the same issue.

I have tried multiple simple examples that should be working. There are no package loading errors

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool, Pool

def square_it(x):
    return x*x

# On Windows, make sure that multiprocessing doesn't start
# until after "if __name__ == '__main__'" 

with Pool(processes=5) as pool:
     results = pool.map(square_it, [5, 4, 3, 2 ,1])

print(results)
```

I expect for my code to complete all code.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting an error, my console shows it is just running that line of code and will not stop. The code should take less than 1 second to run, with one core, so there is not an issue.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is meant to run `square_it` in parallel, in 5 different processes

```
def square_it(x):
    return x*x

with Pool(processes=5) as pool:
    results = pool.map(square_it, [5, 4, 3, 2 ,1])

print(results)
```

The way it does that is by creating 5 new processes, then in each of them, the same python module is loaded and function `square_it` is called.

What happens when the module is imported in one of the 5 subprocesses is the same thing which happens when it is initially loaded in the main process: it creates another `Pool` of 5 subprocesses, which do that indefinitely.

To avoid that, you have to make sure that the subprocesses do not recursively create more and more subprocesses. You do that by creating the subprocesses only in the "main" module, aka `"__main__"`:

```
def square_it(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool(processes=5) as pool:
         results = pool.map(square_it, [5, 4, 3, 2 ,1])

    print(results)
```